# How to use a mouse with DirectFB

Tags: c, linux, directfb, vesa

I am using DirectFB(without X, using fbcon driver(with vesafb) to write to screen buffer). I can do keyboard input, but I want to use my mouse.(Get cursor coordinates/Show cursor/Click events)

Can someone give example code or tell me how it's done? Also do I need GPM for it? I tried mplayer which is based on directfb and the mouse works fine with it without having the GPM daemon started.

Should I use SDL instead or can DirectFB do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried SDL. Works like a charm, no X needed or anything else for that matter, just one executable plus libraries. No GPM needed too. I am so happy right now :)